# removing subview (uiview) in viewcontroller from collectionview

Tags: ios, swift

How do I remove a `uiview` that is added into a `viewcontroller` whenever the user clicks on one of the `collectionview`? My `collectionview` is located inside of its own `viewcontroller` when the user clicks one of the `collectionviewcell` it will dismiss the controller (it's working) and then it will remove the `contextTxt` within the `mainviewcontroller`  It did dismiss the view but it failed to remove the `contextTxt` and replacing it with a new view. In other words, the `collectionviewcell` did not trigger the `@objc` func inside the `mainviewcontroller`. Why won't it trigger?? and how do resolve this problem? Here is the code

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {

    let navbar:navbarView = {
       let content = navbarView()
        return content
    }()

    let contentTxt:UITextView = {
       let content = UITextView()
        content.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return content
    }()

    let bottomBtn:UIButton = {
       let content = UIButton()
        content.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return content
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentTxt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(navbar)
        view.addSubview(contentTxt)
        contentTxt.addSubview(bottomBtn)

        navbar.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        navbar.centerXAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        navbar.widthAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        navbar.heightAnchor.constraint(
            equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        contentTxt.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        contentTxt.centerXAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentTxt.widthAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        contentTxt.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        bottomBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: contentTxt.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: contentTxt.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(
            equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        bottomBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(
            equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func addConnections(){
        self.contentTxt.removeFromSuperview()
        let connect:connectView = {
            let content = connectView()
            content.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return content
        }()

        connect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(connect)
        connect.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        connect.centerXAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        connect.widthAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        connect.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func sideController(){
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "sideViewController") as! sideViewController
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func profileController(){
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! profileViewController
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Here is the `collectionview` code:

```
class sideCollectionView:UIView, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var currentVc:sideViewController?
    var mainVc=mainViewController()
    let arrayLbl = ["connection","achievement","template","setting"]
    let arrayImg = ["connection","achievement","template","setting"]
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayLbl.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! sideCollectionViewCell
        cell.titleImg.image = UIImage(named: "\(arrayImg[indexPath.row])")
        cell.titleLbl.text = arrayLbl[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.frame.width / 2) - 40, height: (self.frame.width / 2) - 40)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 10, 25)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            print("connection")
            currentVc?.bye()
            mainVc.addConnections()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            print("achievement")
            currentVc?.bye()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2{
            print("template")
            currentVc?.bye()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 3{
            print("setting")
            currentVc?.bye()
        }
    }

    lazy var collectionViews: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews(){
        collectionViews.register(sideCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        addSubview(collectionViews)
        collectionViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `var mainVc=mainViewController()` creates a new `mainViewController` which is not the existing `mainViewController`.
You can try getting the parent mainViewController by this way.

```
var mainVc: mainViewController? {
    return currentVc?.presentingViewController as? mainViewController
}
```

Comment: it does not change anything, i still get the same result

Comment: Updated the answer, how about this time?

Answer (score 0):

When presenting sideViewController, set the mainVc variable to self so that it is pointing to the actual mainVc object:

```
@objc func sideController(){
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sideViewController") as! sideViewController
    next.mainVc = self
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: i was trying to execute @objc func addConnections(). not sideController()